# Finding the IP-address and the host name for a database hosted online

Tags: jdbc, server, ip, localhost, hostname

Trying to create a login application that has its data stored on the server.
This is the database I have hosted on https://in.000webhost.com - [Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T226.png)

Now i wish to know the host name and the IP-address of database server, According to the screenshot my host name will be 'localhost' but i am not understanding why? because since the database is hosted online it should not be 'localhost' right??

And also how can i find the IP-address?

Thank you.

Comment: It will be `localhost` because you are expected to be running the Apache PHP server module on the same host as the database is running in.

Comment: Am seeing `cloudflare-nginx` as the web-server for `https://in.000webhost.com`. Is it acting as a reverse proxy hiding the actual ip?

Comment: jdbc api has `Connection` interface which has an abstract method `DatabaseMetaData getMetaData() throws SQLException;` and `DatabaseMetaData` appears to have database url and related info. Could be helpful